# RecyclerView shows up only after an icon is pressed

Tags: android, kotlin, adapter, android-recyclerview

When I get into the activity which supposed to feature the RecyclerView, it doesn't show the ReyclerView right away. For some reason, it shows the RecyclerView only after I press the SearchView icon.

[After I press the search icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woSL7.jpg) and
[Before I press the search icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oXX0.jpg).
Here is my Adapter for RecyclerView:

```
class BlogRecyclerAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
        var con = recyclerView.context
    }


     var items: List<BlogPost> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return BlogViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.user_row, parent, false)
            )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when(holder) {

            is BlogViewHolder ->{
                holder.bind(items.get(position))
            }
        }
    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    fun submitList(blogList: List<BlogPost>){
        items = blogList
    }

    class BlogViewHolder constructor(
        itemView: View
    ): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val phoneButton = itemView.phoneButton
        val locationButton = itemView.locationButton
        val nameButton = itemView.nameButton

        fun bind(blogPost: BlogPost){

            //שם
            nameButton.setText(blogPost.name)

            //אפטר
            if(blogPost.place=="after"){
                locationButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F03434"))
                locationButton.setText("אפטר")
            }
    }
}
```

And this is the Activity that supposed to show the RecyclerView and also contains the search bar:

```
class Tavla : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var blogAdapter: BlogRecyclerAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tavla)

        initRecycelrView()
        addDataset()

    }

   //The method which the search button calls
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)
       val item = menu!!.findItem(R.id.action_search)
        val searchView = item.actionView as androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    private fun addDataset(){
        val data = DataSource.createDataSet()
        blogAdapter.submitList(data)
    }

    private fun initRecycelrView(){
        recyclerView.apply {
            recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@Tavla)
            val topSpacingDecoration = TopSpacingItemDecoration(30)
            addItemDecoration(topSpacingDecoration)
            blogAdapter = BlogRecyclerAdapter()
            adapter = blogAdapter
        }
    }
}
```

I get the list from "DataSource"

Comment: What method is called by the search button?

Comment: onCreateOptionsMenu

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `blogAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` below `addDataset()` in `onCreate`

So that it would notify the adapter that the data has been changed on load of the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Paste this in oncreate method.

addDataset()
initRecycelrView()

Comment: I added the lines you told me to add in the other comment, but I don't understand how to do what you told me to do in this comment. Can you write the code and instructs me where to put it just like you did in the other comment?